# Sending Keyboard Commands

Tags: c++, winapi

How would I send a keyboard command, so that they press "Y", then hit enter. Thanks

Comment: You wouldn't - C++ has no concept of a keyboard.

Comment: I was thinking of using keybd_event(), and they are the users who use my program, im making a simple hang man, and when they get down to the last letter, it types it for them if they have been perfect so far.

Comment: You need to specify which platform you intend to target.

Comment: Im on win xp, so prob win xp.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a CodeProject Article on the matter: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/sendkeys_cpp_Article.aspx

And an msdn article describing how to do it:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171548.aspx

And Another CodeProject Article describing how to use keybd_event():
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/keyboard.aspx

Not sure how this works (I'm not a C++ developer),  but it's supposed to send the letter "a" to notepad (you'll need to have a file open called "test.txt"): From Expert's Exchange (I added in the corrections, but I didn't try running it): http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Programming_Languages/Cplusplus/Q_21119534.html

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0501
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void main()
{
char end;
HWND windowHandle = FindWindow(0, "test.txt - Notepad");
INPUT *key;
if(windowHandle == NULL)
 cout << "not found";
SetForegroundWindow(windowHandle);
Sleep(1000);

key = new INPUT;
key->type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
key->ki.wVk = 41;
key->ki.dwFlags = 0;
key->ki.time = 0;
key->ki.wScan = 0;
key->ki.dwExtraInfo = 0;

SendInput(1,key,sizeof(INPUT));

key->ki.dwExtraInfo = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;

SendInput(1,key,sizeof(INPUT));
cout << "key inputted";
cin >> end;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> im making a simple hang man, and when they get down to the last letter, it types it for them if they have been perfect so far

You're making this way too complicated if you're trying to simulate a keyboard press just to implement this.

Presumably, in your code you have something like:

```
void OnKeyPress(char key)
{
    // handle the key: is it correct, etc?
}
```

All you need to do is call that method directly when they get to the last letter and are perfect so far. You do not need to "simulate" a keyboard event at all.

Comment: True, but I would like to learn on how to simulate a keyboard.

Comment: @pure841: fair enough then :)

Answer (score 0):

use something like this:

```
int main()
{
char ans;
cout << "question";
cin >> ans;
cin.get();
if(ans==y)
{
do something;
}
cin.get();
return0;
}
```

this will set the variable 'ans' to your input using the cin >> function.